# Unexpected data changes after making use of the add index column followed by merge/expand in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Getting an extremely strange behaviour with using ADD INDEX column, followed merge/expand.

Basically I have 2 tables. Both have a common textual key column. I'm trying to add an index to the dim table followed by merge fact with dim, and pull the index into the fact table. So that effectively my model joins on the index column.

But at each data refresh, the index value that's now in the fact record is that of a different dimension record. It appears as thought the dimension index is re-evaluated post merge again.

Steps to replicate:

1. In transform data, I added a new query (table) called ProductDim, this is a SQL server data source and I have provided the SQL statement to list the distinct product list. Columns are:
   Key,client,product

The key looks like: `12|43|client name|product`

The above column is having unique values.

Example of row:
12|43|bmw|x1, bmw, x1

Then I add an index column starting from number 1 (this is via the Add Index column feature in power query).

2. Next I add another query (table) called SalesFact, this is also a SQL server data source and I have provided the SQL statement to list the sales. This has the same kind of product key structure as the key from above.

Then I merge SalesFact to ProductDim on this key column. And then expand ProductDim.Index

Then I delete the key column from the fact table.

3. Finally in the model I create a relation between the index in both tables.

Issue: I have a table visual with product and sum(salesamt). Everytime I refresh the dataset the sum value changes. Is this some kind of bug?

At each refresh the product dimension gets different sales amount value which indicates some issue with the merge/expand.

It appears as though the ProductDim's index is re-evaluated after the merge. Why would that be? If not then what else explains this behaviour?

What is the solution? Is it to sort before adding the index? Or maybe sort after adding the index? Or using table.buffer and when?

The following scenario also gives me the same issue:

Say I have one fact table (id, date, product, amt). And I want to make this into a star schema so I duplicate this table and name it as DimProduct, remove columns other than Product, remove duplicates, add index column; then merge fact table with this Product table and pull the id into the fact table. In the model I link fact table to product and index column. At each refresh I'm observing that the fact records id refers to a different product record.

Comment: Why do you need the indexes if you already have a key?

Comment: The key is a large value like this: `12|43|client name|product`. All I'm doing is create an index and use that as the link in the final model. Basically I'm doing this to remove the large key from the fact table. I'm confused why values keep changing.

Comment: Are you able to replicate?

Comment: There are too many variables involved to replicate unfortunately

Comment: Guys, the database query is returning the exact same data for respective tables. I ran the SQL couple of times to confirm this. It appears as though the ProductDim's index is re-evaluated after the merge. Why would that be? If not then what else explains this behaviour?

Comment: Infact when I observe the refresh I can see that the fact table is processed twice. Here is what I think happens. First the ProductDim loads. Then the FactSales loads. Then the merge step of FactSales runs during which the ProductDim is re-evaluated. This re-evaluation results in SalesFact to have wrong index values. Probably this can be solved if I sort the ProductDim on the key? Can't find any documentation on the need to do such a sort to solve this.

Comment: Similar to what this person faced: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Index-Column-and-Merge-Issue/td-p/2043055

Comment: The expansion of merge seems to be not deterministic and I can't find any documentation on this behaviour. Any pointers ?

Comment: Other people are facing this issue due to unpredictable behavior of the power query merge/expansion. https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Merge-problems-incorrect-expand/m-p/801225 - surprising to see no documentation on guidelines on how to go about to handle this. Some mention table.buffer, and other say add a sort. Absolutely confusing.

Comment: Can you explain more about this: Then I add an index column starting from number 1. In general, I get the feeling that merges and expansions should take place between fields that have a primary key/foreign key relationship. Your "Index" may be a (what?) - anyway, not a reliable way to create relationships between data. (Note: when I first read your question, I took indexes to mean what they mean in RDBMS's, which would *never* change results of queries). What is this index? What is in it? When is it created? How does it relate to the data in the tables? How are they supposed to be used in BI?

Comment: By index I mean the `add index column` in power query

Comment: There are others facing this challenge when expanding the tables but the solution isn't clear to me https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-Row-disappear-after-expand-column/m-p/643967

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may be related to [Query Folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding).

For your `ProductDim` query, add an additional step at the end similar to:

```
StopFolding = Table.StopFolding( #"Your Previous Step" )
```

Or alternatively, try:

```
BufferTable = Table.Buffer( #"Your Previous Step" )
```

With the above, hopefully when you merge, it will take `ProductDim` as is and not fold back to SQL where in theory a different index could be generated.

Comment: the steps in dimension are Source (this is the SQL) and Add Index. I don't think the later folds. Anyways adding table.buffer seems to solve the problem but not sure whats going on

Comment: Also noticed that rather than add index, if I use row_number() via SQL to produce the index then this issue doesn't occur, and neither do I need table.buffer

Comment: Here's an example https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Issues/PowerQuery-Merge-Queries-Transformation-Bug-Inconsistent-Data/idi-p/1259468#M59474

Comment: When you Merge fact and dim, it was likely folding back to SQL, so the index was being recreated for that second query hence why you get different results. You can verify this by looking at SQL it produces - see the link in the snaswer for how. Please help mark the answer as Accepted for the benefit of all.

Comment: As per power bi documention, the Add index power query step doesn't fold. So I can't understand how that effects the data refresh to give wrong results. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding#transformations-that-prevent-folding

Comment: Good catch - curious as to why the Table.Buffer solved the issue for you. Perhaps the ordering of the `ProductDim` changes between itself and when it is Merged.

Comment: Looks to be known issue: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Issues/PowerQuery-Merge-Queries-Transformation-Bug-Inconsistent-Data/idi-p/1259468#M59474 - the merge seems to be recalculating the index I'm not sure why this hasn't yet caused a noise.

Comment: So the solution is to Table.Buffer.

Comment: Well I think so. But since there's not enough clarity on whether I must buffer the dim or even the fact. So for now I've used SQL ROW_NUMBER() to generate the index, and then I'm doing the merge as usual in Power BI

Answer (score 0):

Indexing messes the data in the backend. Each time we refresh the data the random indexes are formed. We need to use Table.Buffer() to create a local copy of the table. Table.Buffer protects from this folding.

Before merging both tables, use Table.Buffer on each table, *then* do the merge. Problem discussed on BI community [here](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Change-in-Index-After-Expanding-Merged-Table-Columns/td-p/1602578).

Comment: Simply sorting before adding index seems to resolve the issue for me. Are you sure buffer is required?

Comment: glad to hear variable. It may not be required in your case.

Comment: But is sort a conclusive solution? When exactly do I need to also add buffer? I am looking for a reliable solution.